# Actionscript if / else syntax Question

Tags: flash, actionscript, goto

Which of the following best translates the English statement "If it's rainy, we will watch a movie. Otherwise we will go to the park."

```
   a. if (rainy = true) { gotoAndStop ("movie"); }
   b. if (rainy == true) { gotoAndStop ("movie"); }
   c. if (rainy = true) { gotoAndStop ("movie"); } else { gotoAndStop ("park"); }
   d. if (rainy == true) { gotoAndStop ("movie"); } else { gotoAndStop ("park"); }
```

My answer would be "d" - is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, 'd' is the correct answer.

The difference between `=` and `==` is that `==` compares and returns a Boolean (true or false) which you operate upon (called 'branching').

`=` is called the assignment operator and while perfectly valid code to write, is not what you normally want to use in an if statement.

```
if(x = 5) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Basically means "put 5 instead of x; if x is non-zero call doStuff".

Another thing to note is when it comes to booleans, it's "safer" to write

```
if (rainy) {
    gotoAndStop("movie");
} else {
    gotoAndStop("park);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or...try this, does the same.... but looks sexy :)

```
var activity:String = (rainy) ? "movie": "park";
gotoAndStop(activity);
```

Comment: A) this is not an answer to the question. B) It is conceivable the OP does not know of ternary operators. Could you provide a bit more context to what the statement does.

Answer (score 0):

This is cool too:

```
gotoAndStop(rainy ? "movie" : "park");
```