# How to make an else and if statement with dynamic text field?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a dynamic text field that populates with a number when clicked. If 2 is shown in the text field, and the user clicks it, then 1 should show, and if 1 is shown, and the user clicks, 1 should show again. But with my code there seems to be a problem. Instead, when 2 is shown and it gets clicked, 1 shows, but if you click it again 2 doesn't show back up. How can I solve this?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var onoff:Number;
onoff = 2
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
options_mc.onoff_txt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tick);
function tick(event:MouseEvent)
{
if(onoff = 1)
{
onoff = 2
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
options_mc.onoff_txt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tick);
}
else(onoff = 2)
{
onoff = 1
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
options_mc.onoff_txt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tick);
}
}
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, `==` tests equality. You are assigning values to `onoff` in your conditionals. `else(onoff = 2)` should be `else if (onoff == 2)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324272/actionscript-if-else-syntax-question

this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To set a value you should use `=`
- The operator equal is `==`

so when you test you should do :

```
if(onoff == 1)
```

[All of this is well explained in this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html)